# Pandas Apply returns matrix instead of single column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

This is probably a stupid question, but I have been trying for a while and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a dataframe:

```
   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A','A', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'E'], 'Other': [999., 999., 999., 999., 999., 999., 999., 999.]})
```

I now want to create a new column based on the column `Type`. For this I have second dataframe:

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['A','B','C','D','E','F', 'G'],'Value':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]})
```

that I am using as a lookup table.

When I try something like:

```
    df1.apply(lambda x: df2.Value[df2.Type == x['Type']],axis=1)
```

I get a matrix instead of a single column:

```
    Out[21]: 
        0   1   2   4   5   6
    0   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    2 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
    3 NaN NaN NaN NaN   4 NaN
    4 NaN NaN   2 NaN NaN NaN
    5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   5
    6   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    7 NaN NaN NaN   4 NaN NaN
```

What I want however is this:

```
        0
    0   1
    1   1
    2   1
    3   4
    4   2
    5   5
    6   1
    7   4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to achieve this:

```
In [62]:
df1['Type'].map(df2.set_index('Type')['Value'],na_action='ignore')

Out[62]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    4
4    2
5    5
6    1
7    4
Name: Type, dtype: int64
```

If you modified your `apply` attempt to the following then it would've worked:

```
In [70]:
df1['Type'].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2.Type == x,'Value'].values[0])

Out[70]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    4
4    2
5    5
6    1
7    4
Name: Type, dtype: int64
```

If we look at what you tried:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: df2.Value[df2.Type == x['Type']],axis=1)
```

this is trying to compare the 'type' and return the 'value' the problem here is that you're returning a Series with the index of `df2`, this is confusing pandas and causing the matrix to be returned. You can see this if we hard code 'B' as an example:

```
In [75]:
df2.Value[df2.Type == 'B']

Out[75]:
1    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Done! Thanks again